# how to insert noise and save multiple images in different folders using a loop?(matlab)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, noise, save-image

I am new in image processing and I want help. I have a folder (dataset) that contains 1000 images and I want to insert noise 'salt & pepper' with different density noise (0.01,0.02 and 0.03) , I used this line to do this:

```
 im = imread('C:\Users\SAMSUNG\Desktop\AHTD3A0002_Para1.tif');
 J = imnoise(im,'salt & pepper',0.01);
```

Please help me to do this : I want to save the result in 3 folder ( data1 contains images after noise with d=0.01, data2 contains images after noise with d=0.02 and data3 contains images after noise with d=0.03).

any suggestation and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will allow you to select the folder and create the noised pictures in 3 different folders. It will only select the '*.tif' files which you can modify in the code. And if you need to create more noise levels, create a loop to name the folders and files dynamically.

```
% get dir
folderX = uigetdir();

% get files
picFiles = dir('*.tif');

% loop over the files and save them with the noise
for ii = 1:length(picFiles)

    currentIm = imread([folderX, '\', picFiles(ii).name]);

    % create folders if not exist
    if ~exist([folderX,'\noise_0.01\'], 'dir')
        % create folders
        mkdir([folderX,'\noise_0.01\']);
    end
    if ~exist([folderX,'\noise_0.02\'], 'dir')
        % create folders
        mkdir([folderX,'\noise_0.02\']);
    end
    if ~exist([folderX,'\noise_0.03\'], 'dir')
        % create folders
        mkdir([folderX,'\noise_0.03\']);
    end   

    J1 = imnoise(currentIm,'salt & pepper',0.01);       
    imwrite(J1,fullfile([folderX, '\noise_0.01\', picFiles(ii).name]));    

    J2 = imnoise(currentIm,'salt & pepper',0.02);    
    imwrite(J2,fullfile([folderX, '\noise_0.02\', picFiles(ii).name]));

    J3 = imnoise(currentIm,'salt & pepper',0.03);
    imwrite(J3,fullfile([folderX, '\noise_0.03\', picFiles(ii).name]));

end
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution with 2 for loop.

```
%save the noise parameter.
noise = [0.01,0.02,0.03];

for i = 1:1000

%we generate the filename (you can adapt this code)
imname = fullfile('C:\Users\SAMSUNG\Desktop\',sprintf('AHTD3A0002_Para%d.tif',i))
%read the image.
im = imread(imname);

for j = 1:length(noise)

%apply the noise
J = imnoise(im,'salt & pepper',noise(j));
%save image in the right folder
imwrite(J,fullfile('C:\Users\SAMSUNG\Desktop',sprintf('folder%d',j)));

end
end
```

Comment: 'Error: File: test.m Line: 17 Column: 77
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket'.

Comment: I haven't tested my code, but... you just have to count the number of parenthesis to correct the error,... try also to think by yourself. by the way I added a parenthesis.

Comment: Error using imwrite (line 426)
Unable to determine the file format from the filename.

Error in test (line 18)
imwrite(J,fullfile('C:\Users\SAMSUNG\Desktop\',sprintf('folder%f',noise(j))));

Comment: I edited my answer but the answer is an example, you need to adjust the code for what you want